# Absolute centering of only one child while second child appears below it

Tags: html, css

So the < H1 > needs to be vertically and horizontally aligned center in a container that I can do with display:flex but the problem is that I want < H2 > to appear horizontally centered but below < H1 > ... you can see the issue in the image and code below. Any idea how do I make < H2 > not follow flex but still appear below absolutely centered < H1 >?

< H2 > pushes < H1 > up making it off centered vertically.

[image]

```css
h1, h2 {margin:0;}

div {
  border:1px solid; 
  text-align:center; 
  margin:50px; 
  padding:50px 0; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  align-content: center; 
  justify-content: center;
  }

h1 {font-size:100px; background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</h1>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: H1 inside your div is already in the center vertically, so I am not sure why you want H2 to be vertically centered as well, its the same div ! You can put it inside another div that will take care of vertically centered as well

Comment: try using `flex-flow: column wrap` as you have one column of 2 rows...

Comment: @RenevanderLende - tried using that but still can't make it work. If H2 is display:none then H1 is immediately absolutely centered.